# Can I have an array of nested numba objects?

Tags: python, llvm, numba

Say I have 2 classes, A and B, that I have jitted, where B has a list of A.  Is this possible in numba?

```
from numba import jitclass, deferred_type
from numba.types import string

spec = [('name', string)]


@jitclass(spec)
class A:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

a_type = deferred_type()
a_type.define(A.class_type.instance_type)
spec2 = [('name', string), ('alist', a_type[:])]
@jitclass(spec2)
class B:
    def __init__(self, name, alist):
        self.name = name
        self.alist = alist
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
python3: /opt/miniconda/conda-bld/llvmdev_1498055795382/work/llvm-4.0.0.src/lib/IR/DataLayout.cpp:638: unsigned int llvm::DataLayout::getAlignment(llvm::Type*, bool) const: Assertion `Ty->isSized() && "Cannot getTypeInfo() on a type that is unsized!"' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Is there any way I could get around this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few limitations to what you are trying to do:

- Numba can't turn a string into a native type, so as far as I'm aware, you can't have instance variables of type `string`
- Numba does not support arrays or lists of objects as arguments to numba-jitted functions or jitclasses.

So numba might not be a good fit for your use case unless you can convert the strings to some native type (maybe an integer label and then remap to strings outside of the numba calls), and represent `A` as a series of homogenous numpy arrays or lists.

Comment: Is this possible in the latest version of Numba (=0.48.0)..?